# Installing 16.04LTS replacing the existing 12.04LTS on a dual boot system with windows

Tags: 12.04, 16.04

I searched enough. But not able to find the right answer. So, please help. I currently have a dual boot system (windows ) and Ubuntu 12.04LTS installed. i created a 16.04LTS USB stick and wanted to replace the existing 12.04LTS. I checked the 16.04LTS install and decided to proceed with that.  I started install process and got confused. So, I decided to go back and exit. After the exit, the laptop never gave me a boot option (to boot either from Windows or Ubuntu). Started hanging. Found no choice but to continue with the install process. Following is the partition table information. I am stuck at this point and don't know how to proceed further.

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root  
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-root  157387 MB
/dev/mapper/ubuntu-vg-swap1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu_vg-swap1  2105MB
/dev/sda
/dev/sda1 ntfs 510MB  25MB Windows7 (loader)
/dev/sda5  --  159528MB unknown
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: First, you need to repair your windows. Do a boot with a Window 10-discboot. So you must repeat the process of installing a brand-new ubuntu, since as your log indicates 12.04 was purged and supposed previous ubuntu partition is gone.